# 'Error running unnamed: server.xml does not contain virtual host 'localhost'

Tags: apache, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set up my virtual server with Apache and for some reason my IntelliJ is giving the error message:

> Error running unnamed: server.xml does not contain virtual host 'localhost'.

I was trying to follow a guide but I have no idea why I'm doing them.... Everything was working perfect for port `8080` but now I'm ready to deploy on `80` and I cannot get things working. Here are my files that I changed

`Server.xml` for apache:

```
<Host name="www.someServer.net" appBase="webapp"
              unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
              xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
            <Context path="" docBase="C:\Program Files (x86)\Server\apache-tomcat-8.0.11\webapps\www.someServer.net\ROOT" reloadable="true"/>
            <Alias>someServer.net</Alias>

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="www.someServer.net_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/>

      </Host>

 <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="www.someServer.net">

 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

I also went into the `Run/Debug Configurations` and went to `Startup/Connection` and added an Environment Variable - `CATALINA_BASE` and the value as the location of my `apache-tomcat-8.0.11`.

Both my Apache and project are in different locations. I have already set up the name cheap account to direct to my IP-address too as "A address". At this point I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but looks like Intellij (my version Ultimate 2018.3.5) requires to have Host with name="localhost" because it starts Tomcat first with localhost and only then on running Tomcat deploys artifacts.

I was trying to configure server.xml with  and the only Host with name="mydomain.abc". It starts and works normally using Eclipse, but always fails with same error on IntelliJ.
In my Windows hosts file I point mydomain.abc to 127.0.0.1 IP.